# Can we get the Visual Studio Developer Powershell title to show the current working directory like the regular Powershell does?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio

I know that you can show the current working directory in the Powershell title bar by adding the following line to your profile...

```
$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = Get-Location
```

However, that only affects a regular Powershell window. If you're using the Developer Powershell (aka terminal window) in Visual Studio, the title remains at "Developer Powershell". This can be very frustrating when you have several terminals open, and need to find the right one.

Anyone know if it's possible to change the title for the terminal window?

Thanks

**Update** Turns out this isn't possible, but I added a [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Developer-Powershell-window-should-respe/10071880) for it. Please feel free to vote if you think this would be useful.

Comment: You can set the terminal name in VS Code via ctrl+shift+P > `Terminal: Rename` > [new name]. I'm not aware of any way to have powershell tell VS Code to run a command like this

Comment: Or you can set up terminal custom titles using VS Code variables like `${cwd}` for current working directory like this answer suggests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69430613/7411885

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Thanks for the comments, but as far as I can see, they only apply to VS Code, not to the full Visual Studio. Ctrl-Shft-P doesn't do anything for me in VS, and I can't see where I'd enter those config settings as VS doesn't seem to have an equivalent. Shame, as it looks exactly like what I'd want. Any suggestions for the full VS? Thanks again.

Comment: It looks like VS only uses the name in the terminal profile: search  "Environment > Terminal", and create new terminal profiles with different names and/or starting paths. I didn't find any variables supported here, but I'm also not very familiar with VS

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Thanks for the reply. Looks like you can't do it. One of the command line options passed to PS in the default setting is `-SetDefaultWindowTitle `, but removing that didn't make any difference. I can't even find any documentation as to what that option does which doesn't help! Thanks again

Comment: Yep, I think that does the same thing as `[System.Console]::Title = 'MyTitle'`, which the VS console window does not actually display